# How can I automate the XML Parsing using JDOM

Tags: java, element, sax, root, jdom

I have to parse an XML file using JDOM and get some infos from all his elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element1>something</element1>
    <element2>
        <subelement21>moo</subelement21>
        <subelement22>
            <subelement221>toto</subelement221>
            <subelement222>tata</subelement222>
        </subelement22>
    </element2>
</root>
```

So, for the element1 it's easy. But for the element2 I have to go through his children and if the children has children go through them too and so on.

```
public static void getInfos(Vector<String> files) {     
    Document document = null;
    Element root = null;

    SAXBuilder sxb = new SAXBuilder();

    for (int i =0 ; i< files.size() ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("n°" + i + " : " + files.elementAt(i));
        try
        {
            document = sxb.build(files.elementAt(i));
            root = document.getRootElement();

            List<?> listElements = root.getChildren();
            Iterator<?> it = listElements.iterator();

            while(it.hasNext())
            {
                Element courant = (Element)it.next();
                System.out.println(courant.getName());

                if(courant.getChildren().size() > 0)
                {
                    // here is the problem -> the element has a children
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

What do you suggest in this case, like a recursive call or something else so I can use the same function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use SAX. I'd keep a stack in the contenthandler that tracked what my current path was in the document, and keep a buffer that my characters method appended to. In endElement I'd get the content from the buffer and clear it out, then use the current path to decide what to do with it.

(this is assuming this document has no mixed-content.)

Here's a link to [an article on using SAX to process complex XML documents](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2000/jw-1006-sax.html), it expands on what I briefly described into an approach that handles recursive data structures. (It also has a predecessor article that is [an introduction to SAX](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2000/jw-0804-sax.html).)

Comment: What do you mean by mixed content

Comment: @OpenMind: mixed content is like what you see in html, where you have things like "<a>asdf<b>zxcv</b>qwerty</a>", so that <a> has more than one element text node.

Comment: I have a lot of this things in my xml files, so I think your method won't work for me ?

Comment: @OpenMind: I'm not sure, hard to know without an example (your example in the question doesn't have any mixed-content). could be it just needs to track more info about what's pushing or popping off the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [XPath](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/xpath/XPath.html) to get the exact elements you want. The example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181055/jdom-xpath-and-namespace-interactions/3181689#3181689) uses namespaces but the basic idea holds.